# scala type mismatch osmosis

Tags: scala, openstreetmap, osmosis

I try to get the example from [this open book about map matching](https://raazesh-sainudiin.gitbooks.io/scalable-data-science/content/db/studentProjects/01_DillonGeorge/039_OSMMap2GraphX.html) to work. I am using scala 2.10 and spark 2.0.2.

Unfortunatelly the syntax and functions have changed.

```
case class NodeEntry(nodeId: Long, latitude: Double, longitude: Double, tags: Array[String])

val nodeDS = nodes.map{node => 
NodeEntry(node.getId, 
   node.getLatitude, 
   node.getLongitude, 
   node.getTags.map(_.getValue).toArray
)}.toDS.cache
```

I get the Error "value map is not a member of java.util.List[org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.v0_6.WayNode]"

and
"value toDS is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Nothing] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDS'?"

I tried to change the nodes.map to the following:

```
val nodeDS = nodes.map { node => 
  NodeEntry(node.getId, 
      node.getLatitude, 
      node.getLongitude, 
      node.getTags.toArray() 
  )}
```

But then I get this Error:
type mismatch; found : Array[Object] required: Array[String] Note: Object >: String, but class Array is invariant in type T. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as _ >: String. (SLS 3.2.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is not available on Java collections inorder to make it available `import JavaConversions`

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Example

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val l = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
l: java.util.ArrayList[String] = []

scala> l.add("scala")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> l.add("haskell")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> l.map(x => x.reverse)
<console>:13: error: value map is not a member of java.util.ArrayList[String]
       l.map(x => x.reverse)
     ^

scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> l.map(x => x.reverse)
res3: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(alacs, lleksah)
```

*Notice that after importing map is now available on the java ArrayList*

Comment: `type mismatch; found : Iterable[String] required: Array[String]` is the error I get for the following code. It marks the "_.getValue"  here `val nodeDS = nodes.map { node => 
      NodeEntry(node.getId, 
          node.getLatitude, 
          node.getLongitude, 
          node.getTags.map(_.getValue)
      )}`

Answer (score 1):

Ah I got it. After the suggested Import the following worked:

```
val nodeDS = nodes.map { node => 
  NodeEntry(node.getId, 
      node.getLatitude, 
      node.getLongitude, 
      node.getTags.map(_.getValue).toArray
  )}
```

Comment: ` val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import sqlContext.implicits._` must be in your code, to make the .toDS.cache part work